# How to get the objectId of object in beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, before-save

The client submits a new `recipe`. The `recipe` object includes an array of `cuisines` which are like categories that this recipe belongs to.

In the `beforeSave()` Cloud Code function, I want to create entries in a separate table that have `recipe`s  and `cuisine`s.

In other words, these are my tables:

**`cuisine:`**

```
objectId | name | country | spicy | fat |
-----------------------------------------
```

**`recipe:`**

```
objectId | name | ingredient | author |
---------------------------------------
```

**`CuisineRecipe:`**

```
objectId | cuisine | recipe |
-----------------------------
```

When a new recipe comes in, I want to take its `cuisine` ids and create entries in the `CuisineRecipe` table.

However, in my code, `request.object.id` returns `undefined`.

I guessed this might be because before it is saved it doesn't have an ID. However, I tried changing to `afterSave` and it still doesn't work (i.e. nothing gets saved to DB)

Here's my Cloud Code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Recipe", function(request, response) {
    // CREATE CuisineRecipe ENTRIES

    //getCuisines
    var cuisines = request.object.get("cuisines");
    // FOR EACH cuisines
    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
    _.each(cuisines, function(CuisineObj){
        console.log(CuisineObj.text);

        // Verify that Cuisine exists
        var CuisineQuery = new Parse.Query("CuisinePublic");
        CuisineQuery.equalTo("CuisineId", CuisineObj.text);
        promise = promise.then(function(){
            return CuisineQuery.find({
                success: function(results){
                    console.log("results: " + results);
                    // If results is 1, it exists, everything is good. Proceed to adding CuisineRecipe entry
                    if (results.length == 1){
                        var CuisineRecipe = Parse.Object.extend("CuisineRecipe");
                        var CuisineRecipe = new CuisineRecipe();
                        CuisineRecipe.set("CuisineId", CuisineObj.text);
                        CuisineRecipe.set("Cuisine", results[0].id);
                        CuisineRecipe.set("Recipe", request.object.id);
                        CuisineRecipe.save();
                    }
                },
                error: function(results){
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.log("results: " + results);
                }
            });
        });

        return promise;
    });
    promise.then(function(){
        response.success();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily understand your different classes and their relations but with `request.object.id` you need to specify the class like `request.object.get("cuisines").id`

Comment: I want to get the id of the `Recipe` object being saved